# ruby eventmachine http-request deferrable

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

That's my first time with EM so I really need some help here

so here's the code:

```
EM.run do
  queue = EM::Queue.new
  EM.start_server('0.0.0.0', '9000', RequestHandler, queue)

  puts 'Server started on localhost:9000' # Any interface, actually

  process_queue = proc do |url|
    request = EM::HttpRequest.new(url, connect_timeout: 1).get # No time to wait, sorry

    request.callback do |http| # deferrable
      puts http.response_header.status
    end

    queue.pop(&process_queue)
  end

  EM.next_tick { queue.pop(&process_queue) }
end
```

I've read a couple of articles about EM, now my understanding of above code is the following:

`EM::HttpRequest` is deferrable, which means it won't block a reactor.
But when I try running 50 concurrent connections with `ab`, it only serves ~20 concurrently ( according to `ab` report ).

But if I place the `process_queue` execution inside `EM.defer`( which means it will run in a separate thread? ) it performs just fine.

Why is it so? `process_queue` just inits a deferrable object and assigns a callback, how does running it inside `EM.defer` makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may want to do is put the `queue.pop(&process_queue)` in the `process_queue` callback inside an `EM.next_tick`. Currently you're going to process all of the queued connections before you allow anything new to connect. If you put the `queue.pop` into a `next_tick` call you'll let the reactor do some work before you process the next item.